# JSONP Callback - JQuery and other frameworks

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

Why do JQuery and other Javascript frameworks (angularjs etc) make up the name of the callback function?

What would be the issues of using a fixed name such as "jsonp"?

JSONP:

```
jsonp({"Name": "Foo", "Id": 1234, "Rank": 7});
```

Comment: We won't be making only one JSONP calls. If you keep the name constant, new callback will override the old one which is not right

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the issues of using a fixed name such as "jsonp"?

If you have two parallel request, you will need to know which of them loaded. Admittedly, there are other ways to find out, but just using different callbacks with different names is the easiest.

Comment: When you say "If you have two parallel request, you will need to know which of them loaded." How do I know which one loaded? e.g. If i have a button that makes a request and gets a response and updates the page. If I push the button fast twice. I will have 2 parallel requests either could complete first, and update the page. How do I know to ignore the first request?